# Need to figure out equivalent object in vb.net from real basic

Tags: vb.net, xojo

I am trying to figure out what I can use in visual basic .net that would act similar to this
http://docs.xojo.com/index.php/MemoryBlock
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use an array `Byte()` or `List(Of Byte)`, or manipulate memory directly with the `System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal` class's `.AllocHGlobal` method with `IntPtr`. Note that VB.NET does not allow for pointer arithmetic like C# does. A common workaround is to use `Marshal` to copy memory from an address into a `Byte` array, perform the work there, then copy it back to the original address.

But we need more information about your ultimate intent. I want to avoid an "XY Problem".